# Given a set of points in a plane, find the maximum number of the all collinear points

Tags: geometry

Given a set of points in a plane，
For example:RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {50, 2}]
How to find the maximum number of the all collinear points

Reference link：https://blog.csdn.net/u014253011/article/details/79770716

```
CollinearQ[list_] := 
 Module[{l = Differences[list]}, 
  Cross @@ PadRight[l, {2, 3}] == {0, 0, 0}]
p = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {30, 2}] // 
   DeleteDuplicates(*Avoid the influence of the same point on \
judgment*);
len = Length[Subsets[p, {2}]];
data = Cases[
   Table[Flatten[
      Select[Join[Subsets[p, {2}][[i]], {#}] & /@ 
        Complement[p, Subsets[p, {2}][[i]]], CollinearQ], 1] // 
     Union, {i, 1, len}], Except[{}]];
(SortBy[#, {1, 1} # &] & /@ data) // DeleteDuplicates
```

How to optimize the speed of this code

Comment: Do you have an algorithm in mind that we might help implement? Otherwise this is more a mathematics / computational geometry problem than a Mathematica one.

Comment: Reference link：https://blog.csdn.net/u014253011/article/details/79770716

Comment: Thank you for posting the link (which you might want to add to the question). Unfortunately the text is in Chinese, which I do not ready, and the code is not Mathematica. It may be better if you could provide an explanation of what the code / algorithm does instead. Otherwise, if you expect somebody to read the code and understand it, then re-implement it in Mathematica for you, you may be waiting a long time :-)

Comment: This appears to be a pretty standard algorithmic problem; see: [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20230/maximum-number-of-collinear-points) or [StackOverflow with pseudocode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557840/find-all-collinear-points-in-a-given-set), or [lecture notes from a programming assignment at Princeton](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring03/cs226/assignments/lines.html).

Comment: If so, what line do you draw if there are 3 of the same point?  `RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {50, 2}]` has a positive probability of getting duplicate points.

Comment: We regard the point of coincidence as a point

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not directly involve anything related to Mathematica.

Comment: Ok,I agree with your suggestion

Comment: @ciao I should have read Q better...agree with comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of points and the number of grid points are not too large, then the brute force method works fine.

```
(* Generate a unique set of points on an m x m grid *)
m = 10;
n = 10;
SeedRandom[12345]; 
x = RandomInteger[{1, m}, {10 n, 2}];
x = DeleteDuplicates[x][[1 ;; n]];

(* Look for 3 points along non-vertical lines *)
points = ConstantArray[0, n];
si = ConstantArray[{0, 0}, n (n - 1) (n - 2)/6];
k1 = 0;
Do[
 Do[
  Do[
   sol = Solve[{x[[i1, 2]] == a + b x[[i1, 1]],
                x[[i2, 2]] == a + b x[[i2, 1]],
                x[[i3, 2]] == a + b x[[i3, 1]]}, {a, b}];
   If[Length[sol] > 0, k1 = k1 + 1; si[[k1]] = {a, b} /. sol[[1]];
    points[[i1]] = 1; points[[i2]] = 1; points[[i3]] = 1],
   {i3, 1, i2 - 1}],
  {i2, 2, i1 - 1}],
 {i1, 3, n}]
si = DeleteDuplicates[si[[1 ;; k1]]];
k1 = Length[si];

(* Look for 3 points along vertical lines *)
vLines = ConstantArray[0, m];
k2 = 0;
Do[If[Length[Select[x, #[[1]] == i &]] > 2, k2 = k2 + 1; vLines[[k2]] = i], {i, m}];
If[k2 > 0, 
  verticalData = Table[{{vLines[[i]], 1}, {vLines[[i]], m}}, {i, k2}], verticalData = {}];
If[k2 > 0, Do[Do[If[x[[i, 1]] == vLines[[j]], points[[i]] = 1], {j, k2}], {i, n}]];

(* k1+k2 unique lines *)
k1 + k2
(* 3 *)

(* Number of points involved *)
Total[points]
(* 6 *)

(* Plot results *)
Show[ListPlot[x, PlotRange -> {{0, m + 1}, {0, m + 1}},
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03], AspectRatio -> 1],
 Plot[#[[1]] + #[[2]] y & /@ si, {y, 1, m}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ListPlot[verticalData, PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True]]
```

[image: Points and lines]

I'm not understanding what you mean by "the maximum number of all of the collinear points."  What the above does is find the total number of points that are associated with a line containing at least 3 points.

Comment: If there are three collinear points, four collinear points and six collinear points in the above figure, the maximum number of all collinear points is six.

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood. If so I will delete. Here is an approach the counts collinear 3 points and collinear >3 points. It is not ideal and seems satisfactory for small sizes but is unlikely to scale well. At baseline duplicate points are removed. The final output has "all the lines" in the left plot and the right plot has collinear sets of points (>3 points). The plot label of the right plot counts the lines.

```
func[n_] := 
 Module[{pts, tr, col, l, dm, over, cnt, ga, ou, x, w, du, mul, gp},
  pts = DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {n, 2}]];
  tr = Subsets[pts, {3}];
  col = Select[tr, Not@NumericQ[Area[Triangle[#]]] &];
  If[col == {}, 
   Return[ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.04], 
     PlotLabel -> "No collinear points"]]; Break[]];
  l = ListPlot[pts, Epilog -> {{Red, Line@#} & /@ col}, 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.04], ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True];
  dm = DistanceMatrix[col, 
    DistanceFunction -> (Length[Intersection[#1, #2]] &)];
  over = Position[UpperTriangularize[dm], 2];
  cnt = Total@Boole[FreeQ[#, 2] & /@ dm];
  ga = GatherBy[over, Last];
  ou = Outer[List, col, col, 1];
  x = Extract[ou, #] & /@ ga;
  w = Join @@@ # & /@ x;
  du = DeleteDuplicates[Union @@ # & /@ w];
  mul = DeleteDuplicates[du, SubsetQ[#2, #1] &];
  gp = Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.04], Point[pts], Black, Line[mul]},
     PlotLabel -> 
     Row[{cnt, "+", Length[mul], "=", cnt + Length[mul]}, 
      BaseStyle -> {Bold, 20}], ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True];
  Row[{l, gp}]]
```

Some examples using `Partition[Table[func[n], 4], 2] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &` for `n`: 15,20,50

[image]

[image]

[image]